# Loopback - Setting Up environment specific configuration

Tags: loopbackjs, loopback

Hi can I get some help with setting environment specific configuration.
I have two files for datasource

1. server/datasources.json
2. server/datasources.test.json

I use the script "SET NODE_ENV=test && mocha test/**/*.test.js" on WIndows to run my test cases and set the node environment to test.
Loopback does not load server/datasource.test.json instead the datasource from server/datasource.json is loaded.

I have confirmend the environment using process.env.NODE_ENV which logs "test

I have tried to change server/datasource.json to server/datasource.local.json, But then I get an error 
WARNING: Main config file "datasources.json" is missing.

I dont understand what I am doing wrong.Am I supposed to create all the config files for the test environment like *.test.json.
Or is there a different config file where I have to define envrionment specific files.

Please check this repo https://github.com/dhruv004/sample-loopback-example
From the code If you run `npm run test` It loads data from local.json which is the data source for development environment.It should load data from `test.json`(datasource for test environment)

Comment: It looks fine. Just to confirm, is the file name `server/datasource.test.json` or `server/datasources.test.json`?

Comment: It is datasources.test.json.The same does not work for config as well.

Comment: One way that I could do it was in my `server/datasources.json` add a new key `"testDb": {
    "name": "db",
    "connector": "memory",
    "file":"test.json"
  }` and then change datasource of the model in `model-config.json`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looking on your [repository](https://github.com/dhruv004/sample-loopback-example), I can see this note from [LoopBack documentation](https://loopback.io/doc/en/lb3/Environment-specific-configuration.html) particulary relevant for you:

A LoopBack application can load multiple configuration files, that can potentially conflict with each other. The value set by the file with the highest priority will always take effect. The priorities are:

1. **Environment-specific configuration**, based on the value of `NODE_ENV`; for example, `server/config.staging.json`.
2. **Local configuration file**; for example, `server/config.local.json`.
3. **Default configuration file**; for example, `server/config.json`.

In your `model-config.json` all models have datasource set to `db` so in your case LoopBack application loads first `datasources.test.json`. It cannot find datasource `db` there (only `testdb`), so it falls back to `datasources.json`. There it finds datasource `db` and it uses it. Try renaming `testdb` in `datasources.test.json` to `db` and it will take a precedense.

Comment: Thanks for the bringing this into my notice, However I have tried renaming `testdb` in `datasources.test.json` to `db`.But it still references the original `datasources.json`.Should I push the latest code for your reference?

Comment: In your npm test script, remove a space before `&&` resulting in `SET NODE_ENV=test&& mocha test/**/*.test.js`, otherwise you end up with 'test ' environment (note the space after).

Comment: This solved my problem.Than you so much..Very silly of me

Comment: You are welcome. An alternative would be double quotes `"test": "SET \"NODE_ENV=test\" && mocha test/**/*.test.js"`. Please consider putting enough information to your question (code snippets from relevant config files), so this Q/A has value even if the links become no longer accessible.

Comment: @IvanSchwarz that comment really helped me.. thanks. please add that comment in your answerr